# Xcode 5: Custom build path in project with multiple targets

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have 3 targets in my project and I want to set a custom build path for one of the targets.  How do I set the build path for just one target in my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Build Products Path build setting to set the custom build path for a single target.

**Update**

I noticed something new in Xcode 5. If you choose File > Project Settings and click the Advanced button, you can choose a Legacy build location that uses the target's build products location.

Comment: I just tried that setting but it only places intermediate build files there.  It still builds the product in the "DerivedData" folder.

Comment: That's odd since there's an Intermediate Build Files Path build setting for intermediate build files. There's a Per-configuration Build Products Path build setting you can try. If that doesn't work and my updated answer doesn't work, I don't have any other solution for you.